# Some links in website main menu keep re-directing to index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, indexing

The following site has a major issue in the top, main menu. If you click on "About", "Bespoke" or "Showroom", it simply re-directs to the home page. In other words you can't access those pages at all.

I'm not the programmer (he is not available at the moment) and only very briefly dabbled in PHP however just wondering if this is a problem with the HTAccess?

Website:
http://www.crestleather.com/index.php

HTAccess:

`#Options +FollowSymLinks`

```
#RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^jmt/(.*)$ index.php?channel=2&q=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be in the that file because all of those lines are commented out. That's what the number sign in at the beginning of the line means.

It appears you're using a CMS and that the issue lies in that PHP code.

Comment: Truth. You'll notice that your URLs are updating correctly - the problem is, all of the URLs that point to "static pages" are taking you to the homepage.